# How do I have a loop with an array of IDs do something upon clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

```
var topOptions = ["#m1", "#m2", "#m3", "#m4", "#m5", "#m6"];
for(i = 0; i < topOptions.length - 1; i++)
{

    $(topOptions[i]).click(function(){
        $(topOptions[i]).animate({backgroundColor: '#2c3e50'}, 150);
      });
}
```

I'm trying to have something happen upon clicking each element, however only the last one is triggered. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).animate ....
```

instead of

```
$(topOptions[i]).animate ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var topOptions = ["#m1", "#m2", "#m3", "#m4", "#m5", "#m6"];
$.each(topOptions,function(i,item){
$(item).animate({backgroundColor: '#2c3e50'}, 150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("a").click(function(){
 var topOptions = ["#m1", "#m2", "#m3", "#m4", "#m5", "#m6"];
 if(jQuery.inArray( $(this).attr("id"),topOptions )>-1){
 $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#2c3e50'}, 150);
 }
 });
```

note that I use a as a selector if it is a div or something else change this

> $("a)

I think you want this function [jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) which check if your clicked id found in topOtions array

Answer (score 0):

Note, you can't animate `backgroudColor` using jQuery animate. You could use css tansition to animate background color. Here is a solution you could use

```js
var ids = ['#id1','#id2','#id3','#id4','#id5'];

ids.forEach(function(id){
 $(id).click(function(e){
  $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#2c3e50')
 });
});
```

```css
li{
 -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-ms-transition: background 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: background 0.5s linear;
transition: background 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
 <li id="id1">id1</li>
 <li id="id2">id2</li>
 <li id="id3">id3</li>
 <li id="id4">id4</li>
 <li id="id5">id5</li> 
 </ul> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

To know about why your for loop working for last element, please check this answer [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)